# What is a good, small GPS data logger that stores accuracy information?

Tags: gps, geotag, hardware-recommendations

I'm looking for a small GPS data logger for geotagging photos, and I've had trouble finding one that meets my requirements:

1. Small, key-fob size would be ideal.  It should also store its tracks on on-board storage.

   I will be carrying it around on my person for days at a time.
2. Good battery life (16 hours per charge and/or on-the-go USB charging or replaceable batteries)

   I can't be fussing with it or stopping to charge during the day.
3. Records accuracy information (HDOP, VDOP, PDOP, satellites in view, etc)

   I want to be able automatically filter out bad data during post-processing.

I've been able to find plenty of units that meet requirements 1 & 2 (see below), but 3 seems like more of a specialist thing and I have had a hard time finding information about what supports it.

I've already tried two loggers, but they've had issues:

[Holux M-241](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0011XV19O): Runs on Alkaline AAs (only high quality), but you need to change them every few hours or it gets flaky (often resulting in data corruption).  It was apparently hackable with earlier firmware revisions to get accuracy info, but the newer versions (which I have) clear the nonstandard config on startup.

[Canmore GP-102+](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QPF9H26): Nice form factor and very good battery life.  However, some of the tracks it recorded had *really* inaccurate sections (probably when the signal was poor) and I had to spend a lot of time editing out the nonsense by hand.  Stores tracks in .fit files that are accessed like a flash drive.  GPSBabel does not appear to find accuracy info in them when I convert them to GPX.

Comment: I haven't looked at this question in a while, but I ended up finding my answer on this wiki has a good, large list of GPS units and their capabilities (including if they can store DOP info): http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GPS_device_reviews.  I would add it as an answer but the question has been locked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Garmin GLO. I found it's accurate to within < 10 feet, often < 6 feet, and provides NMEA data. I don't know about the logging functionality. I build my own processor / logger that connects to the GLO over bluetooth. For a no-code solution, you could connect a smart phone to the GLO and log using the phone and an app from your phone's app store.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent GPS/Glonass receiver, but it is not a data logger: it does not appear to have an internal memory.  I do not want to have to carry around a second device for storage.

Comment: The Garmin Glo is just a GPS receiver that sends the information to another device (eg iPad) via blue tooth. You are right, it's not a data logger and requires an additional application for the logging. When we use it, we attach the Glo to the brim of our hats and then blue tooth the GPS information to an iPone/iPad for logging the information. But this would not suit point 2, as the battery life is around 6 hours and requires it to be recharged through USB.

Answer (score 0):

There's a market for GPS loggers that are placed into packages or shipping cartons and left on while the item is in transit - that way the recipient can review the path the package took to get to its destination.

You might be able to use one of those.

Best example I could find is from this company: [www.keskull.com](http://www.keskull.com/)
(I'm not certain these are precisely what I was describing but I think they might work for you.  I just found that the [product I was referencing is no longer being produced](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/8755).)

They are unfortunately, a bit pricier than one might expect.  The previous answer's suggestion to build a solution might be more cost effective.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a [GiSTEQ PhotoTrackr Mini](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/656648-REG/GiSTEQ_C7_02DPL900_PhotoTrackr_Mini_DPL900.html), which is a slightly oversized USB stick. It creates and stores track logs, primarily for geocoding photos. It has good battery life and charges via USB, however I don't believe it records precision information as you require for point 3.

Comment: Link says that product is no longer available.

Comment: So it does @Kevin. But the general concept of the USB style data logger should still suffice. I'm sure there are others out there.